# Is there a way to select a row programmatically in slickgrid 2.4.3?

Tags: javascript, selection, slickgrid

I have updated my slickgrid table from 2.3.2 to 2.4.3.
All of my code works well, editors, formatters, postrender, etc...
In the old version of the grid i've found a way to programmatically select any row and make a cell editable, and call the onSelectionChange callback function.
After upgrading to new version i'm not be able to make the same thing.

I make a wrapper constructor for the grid, in this class i wrote:

```
...
this.getGrid().setSelectionModel( new Slick.RowSelectionModel() );
....

/**
 * @param {Number} values.id
 * @param {String} values.column
 * @param {Boolean} values.forceEdit
 */
this.selectRow = function ( values ) {
        var row = this.getDataView().getIdxById( values.id );
        if ( values.column ) {
            var cell = this.getGrid().getColumnIndex( values.column );
            this.getGrid().gotoCell( row, cell, values.forceEdit );
        } else {
            setTimeout( function ( ) {
                self.getGrid().setSelectedRows( [values.id] )
            }, 200 )
        }
    }
...
```

In this way the cell goes correclty in edit mode because the editor appears in grid, but the row is not selected properly and the onSelectionChange callback is not called.
The method is the same that i used with the previous version of slickgrid.

Comment: could you possibly create a working example based on one of the current examples?  I usually copy one of the files in the 'examples' folder of the local copy of the repo to the same folder, and then mod it until it demonstrates the problem. pastebin.com is a great tool for sharing that file, which can then be dropped into the examples folder at my end, and hey presto, working example!

Comment: @BenMcIntyre for sure, let me prepare the example and when is ready i'll attach the pastebin. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @BenMcIntyre I create the pastebin example. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VLNXuzhD). I use the example3.html file as base for the code and add some comment to explain it directly on file.
Thanks.

Comment: So, this is a bug that got introduced at some point during the refactoring of the ```setActiveCell``` logic. just released 2.4.7 with a fix. thanks for bringing this to our attention, and sorry for the delay!

Comment: Many thanks @BenMcIntyre. No problem for the delay! Thanks for your support.

Comment: No worries. Usually, I am telling people off for posting usage queries on GitHub, and telling them to use StackOverflow. But for bugs like this, you are most welcome to use the GitHub issue tracker!